# Azure Kubernetes Service - Upgrade 1.25.6 - 1.26.1 API depreciated error

Tags: kubernetes

I have a AKS cluster running and I am receiving an error when trying to upgrade from version 1.25.6 to 1.26.1.

This is the error in full

```
Control Plane upgrade is blocked due to recent usage of a Kubernetes API deprecated in the specified version. Please refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide to migrate the usage. To bypass this error, set forceUpgrade in upgradeSettings.overrideSettings. Bypassing this error without migrating usage will result in the deprecated Kubernetes API calls failing. See details in https://aka.ms/aks/UpgradeAndDeprecatedAPIs. Usage details: 1 error occurred: * usage has been detected on API autoscaling.horizontalpodautoscalers.v2beta2.watch, and was recently seen at: 2023-12-10 19:53:47 +0000 UTC, which will be removed in 1.26
```

I do have a HPA running on my cluster but this is running API version `v2` not `v2beta2`. I have a feeling it's something to do with the control plane that is causing the issue. I attempted to only upgrade the control plane but even that failed due to the same error.

I have even tried to force the upgrade via the UI and that still fails with the same error.

The control plane is managed by Azure so I have no idea how to get around this error.